# VLC read file from stdin

Tags: ubuntu, vlc-media-player

I've tried the following:

```
cat Video_on_the_Web___Dive_Into_HTML5_pr6.webm | vlc -vvv /dev/stdin
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a dash (`-`) instead of `/dev/stdin`.  For example:

```
cat Video_on_the_Web___Dive_Into_HTML5_pr6.webm | vlc -vvv -
```

Comment: Okay it seems that that does work but it does not work for the file I want... VP80 codec